# Is it possible to reopen this question or add some details about what makes it off topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have an on-hold question [Dropping off your resume in person for a job that does not exist](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/38804/dropping-off-your-resume-in-person-for-a-job-that-does-not-exist). Whilst an answer is probably subjective unless anyone is aware of peer-reviewed literature on the matter, I think detailed constructive answers are possible. Given the reason for being on-hold is 'advice on what to do' a charge which could be made against many allowed questions on this site I was wondering if further details can be given on the offending nature so I can avoid it in future and perhaps amend this question.

Answer (score 2):

The question could possibly be edited to fit our format.  For example, it could fit a lot better if the questioned contained more details about the problem you want to solve. In its current form it feels a bit speculative. This doesn't mean there is no hope for the question just that more specifics would give answerers a stronger idea of what kind of job you're applying for, what you have tried unsuccessfully so far, etc.

Perhaps you could also include some research you've found on how to create your own job.  This may also be helpful but is not necessarily required.

This is no guarantee that this makes it fit our topic, but please feel free to jump into The Workplace chat if you want to run anything by core community members.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The question isn't directly for me, it came up in conversation with a relative, I had specifics for him being a young engineer. I removed the details because I figured it made the question too narrow and thus was more of advice which was off topic. Thanks for mentioning the workplace chat I didn't know about that, I may use it for next time.